# How to pause script execution in PyCharm Community?

Tags: python, pycharm

I wrote this piece of code and tried to debug it:

```
from time import *

for i in range (100):
    sleep(1)
    print(i)
```

I first run this script in debug mode, and try to pause it by clicking the pause button, but the **pause** button doesn't work at all, it just keep printing new numbers.

Then I directly run this script (not in the debug mode), the pause did stop pycharm from printing new numbers, but the script is actually still running in the background, when I resume the script, it prints a lot of numbers all of a sudden.

So how can I correctly pause the script execution?

I installed pycharm and python in a whole new windows 7, it still behaves like this.

The stop and rerun button works perfectly, breakpoints too. But the pause button never works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pause ("Pause Output") button only temporarily suspends output to the terminal - it has no effect on the script execution. You may wish to use debug mode with breakpoints instead.

You can add breakpoints into your program by clicking in the space to the left of the text editor (the "Left Gutter", where line numbers appear, if you have them enabled).

See [the Pycharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-breakpoints.html#d414737e52) for more information.

Comment: So ,nothing like that exists in pycharm ? If I want to pause the script execution and resume it later on ,the only choice is using breakpoints?

Comment: Nothing exists like this in pycharm __outside of debug mode__. But why should it? If you are trying to stop execution halfway through some code then you are not running it normally anyway, I'd argue that is always debugging.

Comment: @Artyer I was developing C++ on visual studio in the last 3 years ,newbee to python and pycharm ,sorry .

Comment: Don't worry @iouvxz, I've been using JetBrains' IDEs for a few years and only noticed when you asked that question that the pause button actually only says "Pause Output". :)

Comment: @TomWyllie I am debugging it ,but it just won't pause execution ,it either ignore my pause request or, at best ,it just stop showing its output to me but still keep running in the background .That makes me very confused .

Answer (score 1):

## Update 2022

We now have a pause button in debug mode :

[image]

[image]